# Highlighting certain dates in mat-calendar

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using `mat-calendar`. I am trying to highlight certain dates but I couldn't do it. There is no proper documentation for this.

**HTML**

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-calendar name="appointment_date" [selected]="selectedDate (selectedChange)="onSelect($event)"></mat-calendar>
</mat-card>
```

**TS**

```
onSelect(event){
  this.selectedDate= event;
}
```

What I need:

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> You can use the the input binding `dateClass` as describe in the
>   Angular Material documentation
>   [here](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api#MatDatepicker). **Note:** This requires an Angular Material version of at least 7.1.0

Change your template to this:

```
<mat-calendar [dateClass]="dateClass()" [selected]="selectedDate" (selectedChange)="onSelect($event)"></mat-calendar>
```

And in your component add the `dateClass` function which will generate a function that will return a type of `MatCalendarCellCssClasses`, which can be as simple as a string representing the CSS class to apply (or an array of class names):

```
dateClass() {
  return (date: Date): MatCalendarCellCssClasses => {
    if (date.getDate() === 1) {
      return 'special-date';
    } else {
      return;
    }
  };
}
```

And finally in your `styles.css` add the classes you want applied:

```
.special-date {
  background-color: red;
}
```

> [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-7gm3wt?file=styles.scss)
>   is a stackblitz that colors the first of each month in red.

Comment: I have array of dates, is it is possible to highlight those dates?

Comment: Sure, you could extend the function to check if the date is one that is in your array and then return the required CSS class. The function will be evaluated for each date that is currently show on your calendar.

Comment: `["2019-01-22T18:30:00.000Z", "2019-01-22T18:30:00.000Z", "2019-01-24T18:30:00.000Z", "2019-01-28T18:30:00.000Z", "2019-01-24T18:30:00.000Z", "2019-01-23T18:30:00.000Z", "2019-01-22T18:30:00.000Z", "2019-01-25T18:30:00.000Z"]` I am getting those values from backend. Can you now explain clearly please

Comment: I couldn't import `MatCalendarCellCssClasses` throwing error

Comment: I have updated the stackblitz to check against the array of dates. From here you should be able to adjust/troubleshoot yourself.If not, update your question with what you have tried to resolve it.

Comment: your stackblitz is very clear brother thank you but I couldn't import `import { MatCalendarCellCssClasses } from '@angular/material';` throwing error

Comment: Just saying `throwing error` doesn't really help. What does the error say? Which Angular Material version are you using? `MatCalendarCellCssClasses` is only available from version 7+ as far as I know.

Comment: Error: `Module '"../../../../../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatCalendarCellCssClasses'. [2305]` I am using Material 7.0.1

Comment: You need at least version 7.1.0 of Angular Material. See the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#710-stone-silhouette-2018-11-20), it was added in 7.1.0

Answer (score 12):

Complementing Fabian's answer, if you have problem seeing the highlighted color and you are using `lazy loading` components, remember to add the `::ng-deep` in front of the class. Like this:

```
::ng-deep.special-date {
   background-color: red;
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

If the style is still not applied, try make the style important:

```
::ng-deep.highlight-date {
    background: red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if datas are loaded through service then you have to use `*ngIf="datas"` on the `mat-calendar`, so that `dateClass` will called after the data comes in. ie:

html:

```
<div *ngIf="datas">
  <mat-calendar [dateClass]="dateClass()" ></mat-calendar>
 </div>
```

ts:

```
dateClass() {
  return (date: Date): MatCalendarCellCssClasses => {
    const highlightDate = this.datas.map(strDate => new Date(strDate))
      .some(d => d.getDate() === date.getDate() && d.getMonth() === date.getMonth() && d.getFullYear() === date.getFullYear());
    return highlightDate ? 'special-date' : '';
  };
}


ngOnInit() {
  this.studentreportsService.getHeatMap(this.studentid)
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.datas = data; // ["2019-01-22", "2019-01-24"]
  });
}
```

Comment: This works for me. But I was wondering is there a way to render the calendar at all times?

Comment: Works when i change the month only.

Answer (score 0):

@Fabian Küng's answer on stakblitz was giving me an error stating that `date.getDate()` was not a function.

I solved it by assigning `date` to a `new Date()`. My code looks like this:

```js
return (date: Date): MatCalendarCellCssClasses => {
      date = new Date(date); // <<< My edit
      const highlightDate = this.datesToHighlight
        .map(strDate => new Date(strDate))
        .some(d => {
          return d.getDate() === date.getDate() && d.getMonth() === date.getMonth() && d.getFullYear() === date.getFullYear()
        });

      return highlightDate ? 'special-date' : '';
    };
```