# How to refresh mat-calendar after changing the background of highlighted dates

Tags: css, angular, angular6, angular-material-7

I have a mat-calendar control which is open always. On initial load, I am highlighting an array of dates which was able to do following this: [Highlighting certain dates in mat-calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54438752/highlighting-certain-dates-in-mat-calendar). Now I have to highlight today's day (or selected date) on a button click. The highlighting works only when I change to different month, and then come back to the current month's view. Is there a way to refresh the mat-calendar dynamically? Please advise.

https://am-all-imports-zwnjbd.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can simply use `MatCalendar.updateTodaysDate()` to re-render it.

```
@ViewChild(MatCalendar) calendar: MatCalendar<Date>;

someEvent(){
    this.calendar.updateTodaysDate();
}
```

Comment: This works when using Date class calendar - but not with moment!

Comment: This worked for me, and my calendar returns Moment when selecting a date

Answer (score 3):

I'm using material 7.2 and for me to move the focus it worked updating the property `activeDate`:

```
<mat-calendar
    #myCalendar
    [startAt]="startDate"
    [selected]="selectedDate">
</mat-calendar>

<div>
    <button mat-button (click)="addThreeDays()">
        Add 3 days
    </button>
</div>
```

Then in the component logic

```
@ViewChild('myCalendar') myCalendar;
startDate = '2019-08-26';
selectedDate = '2019-08-26';

addThreeDays() {
   this.myCalendar.activeDate = '2019-08-29';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i haven't found a native method.

here's my workoaround:

put the mat-calendar component inside a div with the condition that the array of highlight dates is not undefined

```
<mat-card *ngIf="datesToHighlight">
  <mat-calendar [dateClass]="dateClass()" [selected]="selectedDate" (selectedChange)="onSelect($event)"></mat-calendar>
</mat-card>
```

when you want to refresh mat-calendar, set the array to null and then fill it with the updated data

```
 this.datesToHighlight = null;
 this.datesToHighlight = getMyNewArray();
```

That way the component will load again with the new array

Comment: Sorry, this did nothing I could see. The rendering optimiser will treat that as no change.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers with "activeDate" are correct, i just want to point out the reason **it does work**.

Long story short, @Input("startAt") is not checked for changes in ngOnChanges hook in MatCalendar, you can see it here: [Problematic line in MatCalendar repository](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/a378147356e2b6a43fa642ecbc69e37f3077fac7/src/material/datepicker/calendar.ts#L411)

And here => [activeDate setter](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/a378147356e2b6a43fa642ecbc69e37f3077fac7/src/material/datepicker/calendar.ts#L327), you will see that **it actualy triggers a state changes detection**.

The weird thing is that **activeDate initial value comes from startAt Input** when it is set, therefore i believe updating startAt Input **should** do it too, but it doesn't...