# how can I make the selected date highlighted (set it's background color) in angular mat-calendar

Tags: angular

I am using `angular` `mat-calendar` in my app to select date from. When I select a date I want that date should be highlighted for better usability. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Is it there any reasons why you're not using mat-datepicker instead? It already has that feature

Comment: Probably a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54438752/highlighting-certain-dates-in-mat-calendar